# Android service is killed 10 seconds after start

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-service, android-background

I need to make a service to catch server messages via websocket and show them in the notification.
First time when I closed the app the service stopped. I made a broadcast receiver in `onDestroy` to restart service after app is closed and swiped from active apps.
But after all system or some other things keep killing the service exactly every 10 seconds.
I see `Not finishing the service, sending broadcast` in logcat, so it wasn't me stopping the service using the command.

"Start command" message appears every 10 seconds in logcat, it means the service keeps restarting every 10 seconds.

**NotificationPuller.kt**:

```kotlin
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import com.packagename.project.ENDPOINT_SERVER_WS
import com.packagename.project.PREFS
import com.packagename.project.PREFS_TOKEN
import com.packagename.project.UnsafeHttpClient
import com.packagename.project.receivers.ServiceRestart
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.WebSocket
import java.util.*

class NotificationPuller : Service() {

    private var finishing: Boolean = false

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service binding")
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start command")
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun onCriticalFailure() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Critical failure, stopping the service")
        stopService()
    }

    private fun onFailure() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failure")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if(!finishing) { // not killing the service completely, restarting it
            Log.d(TAG, "Not finishing the service, sending broadcast")
            val broadcastIntent = Intent()
            broadcastIntent.setClass(this, ServiceRestart::class.java)
            broadcastIntent.action = RESTART_ACTION
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "Service destroyed")
    }

    private fun stopService() {
        finishing = true
        stopSelf()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SERVICE"
        const val RESTART_ACTION = "com.nikitiyproject.RESTART_ACTION"
    }
}
```

**ServiceRestart.kt**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.IntentCompat
import com.packagename.project.background.NotificationPuller

class ServiceRestart : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver restarts service")
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context!!, NotificationPuller::class.java)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "BCR"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation for `startForegroundService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=en#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)):

> Similar to startService(android.content.Intent), but with **an implicit promise that the Service will call startForeground(int, android.app.Notification) once it begins running**. The service is given an amount of time comparable to the ANR interval to do this, otherwise the system will automatically crash the process, in which case an internal exception ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException is logged on logcat on devices running SDK Version Build.VERSION_CODES.S or later. On older Android versions, an internal exception RemoteServiceException is logged instead, with a corresponding message.

(emphasis added)

You are not calling `startForeground()` in your `Service`, to comply with that promise.